# How to change datetimeindex on an x-axis

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn sns

a = pd.read_csv("~~.csv", index_col="dates", parse_dates=True)
sns.countplot(x=a.index, data=a)
```

this plot x-axis ticks display 2021-01-01 00:00:00  but i want to display only date not time(2021-01-01) how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first option: format date in pandas.

```py
# assuming DatetimeIndex:
sns.countplot(x=a.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), data=a)
```

The second option: use matplotlib formatter:

```py
import matplotlib.mdates

ax = sns.countplot(x=a.index, data=a)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
```